# What does the mth argument to RectBivariateSpline do in old (0.9.0) versions of scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm stuck using `scipy` version `0.9.0`.

In that version `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__` has a keword argument `mth`.  Other than the default value (`mth='array'`), I can't tell how it is used, in particular what other options (if any) are supported and what do they do?

The documentation that I have found is for more up to date versions, where the `mth` argument is deprecated (in favor of the `grid` argument). so that is not very useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other option available:

Here's the source code for the function:

```
def __call__(self, x, y, mth='array'):
    """ Evaluate spline at positions x,y."""
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    # empty input yields empty output
    if (x.size == 0) and (y.size == 0):
        return array([])

    if mth=='array':
        tx,ty,c = self.tck[:3]
        kx,ky = self.degrees
        z,ier = dfitpack.bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y)
        assert ier==0,'Invalid input: ier='+`ier`
        return z
    raise NotImplementedError('unknown method mth=%s' % mth)
```